# How to specify a non-positional parameter in a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I've got the following `param` block at the start of a script

```
param(
 [string]$command,
 [string]$version = "1.1.0"
)
```

This is fine, only I need `$version` to *not* be a positional parameter, so that if you type

```
.\script.ps1 run argument
```

Then `$args` should contain "argument" and `$version` should be "1.1.0". I know I can do it with a C# Cmdlet, but it would be more convenient if I could deliver this as a single script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PowerShell 1.0, not possible AFAIK.  You would need to remove the $version parameter if you don't want it to be positional.

In PowerShell 2.0, you can get what you want by creating an advanced function in which you specify additional info in a Parameter attribute e.g.:

```
function foo {    
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 0)]
        [string]
        $command,

        [Parameter()]
        [string]
        $version = "1.1.0",

        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]
        $remainingArgs
    )

    Process {
        $OFS = ','
        "command is $command"
        "version is $version"
        "remainingArgs are $remainingArgs"
    }
}

foo run argument
```

Comment: If you remove the "Position = 0" from the first param, all of the remaning params seem to revert to positional params.  Any idea how one could create a set of params for which _all_ of them are optional?

Comment: If you don't set `Mandatory=$true` (or just remove the `[Parameter()]` altogether) then a parameter is considered optional.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to create a param list with no positional params, I'm afraid.  I'll open up a detailed question about this in a moment.

Comment: I've opened a question for my particular corner-case version of this problem here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375919/powershell-non-positional-optional-params](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375919/powershell-non-positional-optional-params)