# assign powershell params by name only

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a powershell script which has several parameters

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
  [ValidateSet('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')]
  [string] $abcd,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $mandatory1,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $mandatory2,
  [Parameter()] $optional1=$false,
  [Parameter()] $optional2=$false,
  [Parameter()] $defaulted1=256,
  [Parameter()] $defaulted2=30,
  [Parameter()] [string] $defaulted3='defaulted3',
  [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] [string[]] $rest
)
```

However, when I try to call it, some parameters are being assigned to the optionals/defaults instead of to $rest.

```
.\my-script `
  -abcd a `
  -mandatory1 value1 `
  -mandatory2 value2 `
  -optional1 value3 `
  -optional2 value4 `
  -rest `
    foo `
    bar `
    baz
```

my script prints

```
optional1 is value3
optional2 is value4
defaulted1 is bar
defaulted2 is baz
rest is foo
```

So it looks like Powershell prefers to assign things *by position* to arguments even if they have default values, over assigning them to the ValueFromRemainingArguments param.

Is there a way to change this behavior and set an optional parameter's value by name only?

I tried using [How to specify a non-positional parameter in a PowerShell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795582/how-to-specify-a-non-positional-parameter-in-a-powershell-script/2795683) and [Powershell non-positional, optional params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375919/powershell-non-positional-optional-params) but either I did it wrong or it doesn't work the way I thought it would.

Comment: Have a look at [Require and test for named arguments only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042084/require-and-test-for-named-arguments-only/55044910#55044910) and see if that helps. You essentially need to begin your script with `[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]` before the `param` keyword at the top of the script. See [Require and test for named arguments only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042084/require-and-test-for-named-arguments-only/55044910#55044910)

Here is an example of the parameter attribute being applied to your code:

```
function test {
[cmdletbinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateSet('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')]
[string] $abcd,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $mandatory1,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $mandatory2,
[Parameter()] $optional1=$false,
[Parameter()] $optional2=$false,
[Parameter()] $defaulted1=256,
[Parameter()] $defaulted2=30,
[Parameter()] [string] $defaulted3='defaulted3',
[Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] [string[]] $rest
)
$rest
}

test -abcd "a" -mandatory1 "hi" -mandatory2 "hi" "foo" "bar"
foo
bar
test -abcd "a" -mandatory1 "hi" -mandatory2 "hi" -rest foo,bar,baz
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: adding commas between the values I'm trying to pass to $rest seems to have worked! thanks! just a misunderstanding of array syntax the whole time

Comment: You might also consider not having the "Position=0" part of the command that tells it specifically to look for positional parameters.